# knockout.js guideline for ()

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm having difficulty in understanding when I should be using () to call my variables in knockout.js.

Let's say for example:

```
function RandomViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.randomJ = new randomSquare;
}

var randomSquare = ko.observable({
    innate: ko.observableArray([ { star: "randomStar", type: "starList" } ])
});
```

If I wanted to set the text of a div to the element inside randomJ, this would be the code:

```
<div data-bind="text: randomJ.innate()[0].star"></div>
```

The following however do not work:

```
<div data-bind="text: randomJ().innate()[0].star"></div>
<div data-bind="text: randomJ.innate[0].star"></div>
```

I'm just wondering if anyone knows of a clear guideline as to when and how () should be used with knockout.js variable handling - both within html and javascript.

I'm currently refactoring my previous code to work with knockout and I'd like to get a firm grip of concepts before I start jumping into nested arrays of objects, etc. I'd rather not be assuming things.

Any comments on the above javascript are also much welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If variable `var` is an observable, you get its *value* with `var()` (because observables are actually functions that return the current value). But there is a convenient exception: if the expression that you refer to in **data-bind** resolves to an observable, you *may* leave out the parantheses, as knockout.js will recognize the observable type.

Usually, for an observable that contains an object with an observable array of non-observable values, you would *have to* use this:

```
randomJ().innate()[0].star
```

But your example has a flaw: randomJ is actually no observable! In this line

```
self.randomJ = new randomSquare;
```

you use an observable as a constructor function. This is not intended usage and leads to the following result: you get a new object (not a function, in particular not an observable!) with the same *properties* as the observable. The latter is the reason that randomJ.innate is in fact the original observable array of randomSquare.

it should be:

```
self.randomJ = randomSquare;
```

or directly:

```
self.randomJ = ko.observable({
    innate: ko.observableArray([ { star: "randomStar", type: "starList" } ])
});
```

If you intended to use randomSquare as a constructor/factory for several observables, you will have to do it like so:

```
var randomSquare = function() {
    return ko.observable({
        innate: ko.observableArray([ { star: "randomStar", type: "starList" } ])
    });
}
self.randomJ = randomSquare();
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, I'll just ask for a little clarification. Basically `ko.observable`s are used in a way so that they continue to return their current inner value. Yet the moment I do `new randomSquare`, I'm creating an object with the current properties (current observed state), hence I can no longer give back return values of observed inner properties when needed (since the object is no longer a function that can do so) Have I understood this correctly?

Comment: Yes, it's a bit simplified but basically correct. Note that `innate` stays an observable array, so as long as you only change the content of `innate` and not the actual properties of `randomSquare`, the behavior is still as desired.

Comment: You've cleared the confusion I've been having regarding both javascript and knockout.js. Thanks!